# Scalar field propagator in euclidean field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, propagator, wick-rotation

We have a scalar field propagator in minkowski space with signature $(+,-,-,-)$ as

$$ G (k)={1\over 
k^2-m^2 }.$$

But in Euclidean space the scalar field propagator is

$$G (k)={1\over k^2+m^2 }.$$

Can anyone please explain how this conversion  happen?

Comment: The dispersion relation is different. The Propagator in Euclidean spacetime is the green’s function of a different operator.

Comment: Can you please write dispersion relation in Euclidean spacetime@adithya

Comment: It's actually given in Wein Eld's answer below. I suggest you go through that.

Answer (score 6):

The action for the free scalar field theory in Minkowski space is 
$$S_M[\phi]=\int d^4x \left[\frac{1}{2}\eta^{\mu\nu}(\partial_\mu\phi)\partial_\nu\phi -\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2\right]=\int d^4x \left[\frac{1}{2}\phi(-\partial^2-m^2)\phi\right],$$
where $\partial^2=\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu$.
The Green's function is defined as $(-\partial^2-m^2) G(x,y)=\delta^{(4)}(x-y)$. In momentum space, the Green's function takes $1/(k^2-m^2)$ where $k^2=(k^0)^2-\vec{k}^2$ (using the (+,-,-,-) signature for the Minkowski metric).

The Euclidean theory can be obtained by a Wick rotation $t\rightarrow -i\tau$ together with $iS_M\rightarrow -S_E$. Then we have

$$S_E[\phi]=\int d^4x \left[\frac{1}{2}\delta^{\mu\nu}(\partial_\mu\phi)\partial_\nu\phi +\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2\right].$$

Now you have the operator $-\delta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu+m^2$. The Green's function in momentum space is $1/(k^2+m^2)$ where $k^2=(k^0)^2+\vec{k}^2$.

The Klein-Gordon equation is simply
$$\left(-\delta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu+m^2\right)\phi=0.$$
Taking $\phi\sim e^{-i\omega t+i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}$, one has the dispersion relation $\omega^2+\vec{k}^2+m^2=0$, i.e. $\omega=\pm i\sqrt{\vec{k}^2+m^2}$. This means that in Euclidean space, one has decaying modes instead of oscillating modes.

Comment: How you got $S_E [\phi]$

Comment: Wick rotation just changes the metric that we used , metric change is balance by the substitution of complex time @Wein Eld

Comment: @ROBIN RAJ It is just the definition for the Euclidean action. You can have more motivation for that definition if you derive the path integral representation of the Euclidean transition amplitude.

Comment: Can you give the dispersion relation and klein jordan equation in eucledian  space.@Wein Eld

Comment: @ROBINRAJ I updated the answer.